# get list of Objects without using wrapped inner classes using Retrofit

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

I'm consuming an API from my android app, and all the JSON responses are like this:

```
{"firms":[{"firm_name":"f1"},{"firm_name":"f2"}]}
```

what i have done is to create only a POJO class containing the field "firm_name"

```
class Firms {
  private String firm_name;
 //setters and getters
}
```

my ApiService interface:

```
public interface ApiService {

  @POST("functions/firmNamesRequest.php")
Call<Firms> getFirm_name();
}
```

my JsonDeserializer implementation:

```
 public class FirmsDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Firms> {

@Override
public Firms deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
    JsonElement jsonElement = jsonObject.get("firms").getAsJsonArray();

    return new Gson().fromJson(jsonElement, Firms.class); 
}
```

and inside my LoginFragment the implementation of Retrofit's callback methods

```
 private void getFirmNamesToPopulateSpinner() {
    Gson firmsGson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .registerTypeAdapter(Firms.class, new FirmsDeserializer())
                    .create();

    ApiService apiService = ServiceGenerator.createService(ApiService.class, firmsGson);
    Call<Firms> call = apiService.getFirm_name();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Firms>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(retrofit.Response<Firms> response, Retrofit retrofit) {  
          @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

        }
    });
 }
```

i have managed to iterate through the list of firm Objects using wrapped POJO classes ex. a class FirmResponse which contains a list object of type Firms and inside Firms class i have inserted the field firm_name. I consider that FirmResponse class with only an object inside it is redundant and there is a better way to consume the specific API call implementing the JsonDeserializer interface. My question is if there is a way to get the list of firms objects inside on onResponse callback and iterate through them getting the firm_name value?any answers will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally after struggling a lot to figure out the solution to my problem...i manages to resolve it...what i did was to make retrofit api call return an array of type Firms so my ApiService interface:

```
public interface ApiService {

 @POST("functions/firmNamesRequest.php")
 Call<Firms[]> getFirm_name();
}
```

my JsonDeserializer implementation:

```
public class FirmsDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Firms[]> {

private static final String debugTag = "FirmsDeserializer";

@Override
public Firms[] deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

    JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();

    return new Gson().fromJson(jsonObject.get("firms").getAsJsonArray(), Firms[].class);
}
}
```

and the trick that solved the issue was inside my LoginFragment and the implementation of Retrofit's callback onResponse() method..what i did was to assign the POJO response object "response" to an array object of type Firms...so simple..

```
 private void getFirmNamesToPopulateSpinner() {
Gson firmsGson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(Firms.class, new FirmsDeserializer())
                .create();

ApiService apiService = ServiceGenerator.createService(ApiService.class, firmsGson);
Call<Firms> call = apiService.getFirm_name();
call.enqueue(new Callback<Firms>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(retrofit.Response<Firms> response, Retrofit retrofit) {  
     Firms[] firms = response.body();
    for ( int i=0; i<firms.length; i++) {
                Log.d(debugTag,  firms[i].getFirm_name());
            }
  } 
      @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

    }
});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Serialized Retrofit calls? You can set up your Firms class variables with    `@SerializedName("firm_name")` and then make Retrofit calls with `List<Firm>` rather than `Firm[]`. It makes it simpler rather than doing GSON conversions